# How can I configure celery task

Tags: python, asynchronous, celery, distributed, task-queue

I am using Celery in a project, where I am using it as a scheduler( as periodic task).

My Celery task looks like:

```
@periodic_task(run_every=timedelta(seconds=300))
def update_all_feed():
    feed_1()
    feed_2()
    ...........
    feed_n()
```

But as the number of feeds increases it is taking a long time to get to other feeds (e.g when Celery is working with feed number n it takes a long time to get to the next feed (n+1). I want to use Celery's concurrency to start multiple feeds.

After going through the docs, I found I can call a celery task like below:

```
feed.delay()
```

How can I configure celery so that it gets all the feed ids and aggregates them (e.g for example 5 feeds at a time)? I realize that to achieve this I will have to run Celery as daemon.

N.B: I am using mongodb as a broker, all I did was install it and add the url in Celery's config.

Answer (score 0):

You can schedule all your feeds like this

```
@periodic_task(run_every=timedelta(seconds=300))
def update_all_feed():
    feed_1.delay()
    feed_2.delay()
    .......
    feed_n.delay()
```

or you can use a group so simplify it

```
from celery import group
@periodic_task(run_every=timedelta(seconds=300))
def update_all_feed():
    group(feed.delay(i) for i in range(10))
```

Now to run the tasks you can start a worker to execute tasks

```
celery worker -A your_app -l info --beat
```

This starts executing your task every five minutes. However the default concurrency is equal to cores of your cpu. You can change the concurrency also. If you want to execute 10 tasks at a time concurrently then

```
celery worker -A your_app -l info --beat -c 10
```

Answer (score 0):

From the [Celery documentation](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/next/userguide/tasksets.html#task-sets):

```
from celery.task.sets import TaskSet
from .tasks import feed, get_feed_ids

job = TaskSet(tasks=[
        feed.subtask((feed_id,)) for feed_id in get_feed_ids()
    ])

result = job.apply_async()
results = result.join() # There's more in the documentation
```